# How to find the average of an array and pin it with its corresponding name with another array

Tags: python

I have my code set to allow the user to make a list of names for students and another list for their corresponding grades. What I cant seem to figure out is how to take the highest grade, the lowest grade, and the closest to the average then state it with the student it belongs to.

This is what I have so far

```
# creating statements
students = []
grades = []
print('students:',students)
print('grades:',grades)
looper1 = 0
looper2 = 0
studentappend = 0
gradeappend = 0
# list creation
while looper1 != 2:
    print('please choose an option:')
    print('1: add student and grade')
    print('2: Finish step')
    looper1 = int(input())
    if looper1 ==1:
      students.append(input('enter student name: '))
      grades.append(int(input('enter grade:')))
      print('students:',students)
      print('grades:',grades)
    if looper1 ==2:
      break
    if looper1 !=1 and looper1 !=2:
      print('Invalid. enter 1 or 2')

print('students:',students)
print('grades:',grades)
print("Largest element is:", max(grades))
```

On the last line I have it set to say "Largest grade is: 55" for example, but I want to make it say the name the grade belongs to as well. For example "Bill has the largest grade of 55" This will apply to the lowest grade and the grade that is the closest to the average. I was hoping the max() function would print the number that would tell me where the grade I was looking for was located rather then simply stating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with modifications to make your code more streamlined:

```
students = []
grades = []

#gather input
looper = 1
while looper == 1:
    students.append(input('enter student name: '))
    grades.append(int(input('enter grade: ')))
    looper = int(input('Enter 1 to add more data or another number to exit: '))

#calculate closest to mean    
true_mean = sum(grades)/len(grades)
close_to_mean = 0
for i, grade in enumerate(sorted(grades)):
    if grade < true_mean < sorted(grades)[i+1]:
        close_to_mean = grade
        
print('students:',students)
print('grades:',grades)
print(f"Highest grade is: {max(grades)} and belongs to {students[grades.index(max(grades))]}.")
print(f"Lowest grade is: {min(grades)} and belongs to {students[grades.index(min(grades))]}.")
print(f"Closest to mean grade is: {close_to_mean} and belongs to {students[grades.index(close_to_mean)]}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the index location for the highest value in the grades list and use that index to return the corresponding student in the students list.

```py
print(students[grades.index(max(grades))]+" has the larges grade of "+str(max(grades)))
```

Note that the index method returns the index of the first matching item in the list. So if two students are tied with the highest score, it will only return the one listed first.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed, another approach is to use NumPy functions.
`np.argmax` and `np.argmin` give the indices of the (first occurrence of) the maximum and minimum value in an array or list.

To get the name of the student with the highest grade: `students[np.argmax(grades)]`

To get the name of the student with the lowest grade: `students[np.argmin(grades)]`

To get the name of the student with the grade closest to the average, you may need list comprehension to calculate the absolute difference between the average grade and each student's grade:
`students[np.argmin(np.abs([x - np.mean(grades) for x in grades]))]`

Alternatively, instead of list comprehension, you can directly cast it to a numpy array:
`students[np.argmin(np.abs(np.array(grades) - np.mean(grades)))]`